# Obtaining Hibernate's TypeRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wrote a Hibernate `UserType` that does type conversion between my Java class and JDBC `VARCHAR`. I annotated my bean as follows:

```java
@TypeDef...
class MyClass {
    @Column(name = "...")
    @Type(type = "MyPropertyType")
    private MyProperty myProperty;

    @Column(name = "...")
    private Date date;
}
```

Now, the user may specify conditions for this property - and others - via command line. I want to add these conditions to the query using JPAs `CriteriaBuilder`, for example:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(column, operand);
```

Doing so, Hibernate will complain that `operand` (being a string) does not correspond to `MyProperty.class`. Hibernate doesn't try to convert the type automatically (which it could because it knows the target type and it has my annotation which points to a Type that implements `StringRepresentableType`. So I will have to do the type conversion manually.

- Is it possible to explicitly tell Hibernate to try to convert the string to the target type? Or can I get the Type instance for a specific bean property from Hibernate?
- Where can I get Hibernate's `TypeRegistry` in which `MyPropertyType` is registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a second conversion service that converts strings to the target type. I'm using [Spring's conversion facility](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert):

```
@Resource
ConversionService conversionService;

// ...

Object castedOperand = conversionService.convert(operand, column.getJavaType());
```

Hibernate now accepts `castedOperand` in conditions like

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(column, operand);
```

This generally makes sense because the first conversion facility (Hibernate) will convert between JDBC (e. g. `VARCHAR`) and Java types while the second conversion facility (Spring) performs conversions between user input (strings from command line or HTTP requests) and Java types.

Please leave a comment if there's a way to inject the already existing converters from Hibernate's `TypeRegistry` into Spring's `ConversionService` including those classes that implement [`StringRepresentableType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/StringRepresentableType.html).